# How to verify SenderID is working

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

I have recently setup SenderID on my DNS and want to verify that my email is passing. I tried port25 but did not receive an email with a report back from them.

Are there any sites or tools that can be used for verification of SenderID

Answer (score 1):

The SPF project provides an email address that you can send an email and get a report back:

See here for details:
http://www.openspf.org/Tools